# Como sacar todas las lineas de un excel en c#

Tags: c#

Hola me gustaria sacar todas las lineas del diccionario que hice, el problema es que solo me saca una por key.

Adjunto código:

```
private static void LoopAndWritteAC(Dictionary<string, List<Cl_LineaAC>> hashDiccionari)
    {
        string pathFile = @"C:\test\csv\TEST_AC.xlsx"; // donde guardamos el archivo
        SLDocument oSLDocument = new SLDocument();

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable(); // creacion de la tabla

        dt.Columns.Add("documento", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("fecha", typeof(string));
        

        foreach (var key in hashDiccionari.Keys) // bucle para sacar todos las opciones por id
        {

            List<DTO.Cl_LineaAC> lista = hashDiccionari[key];

            Cl_LineaAC_Final linFin = new Cl_LineaAC_Final();

            string doc = lista[0].documento;
            linFin.documento = (doc.PadLeft(6));
            string fec = lista[0].fechaAsiento;
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            var fechaDatetime = DateTime.ParseExact(fec, "yyyyMMdd", provider);
            var fechasalida = fechaDatetime.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
            linFin.fecha= fechasalida;
            

            dt.Rows.Add(linFin.documento, linFin.fecha);

        }
        oSLDocument.ImportDataTable(1, 1, dt, true); // importamos la tabla
        oSLDocument.SaveAs(pathFile);  // guardamos la tabla
    }

}
```

[image: imagen] Como podeis observar deberian salir varias filas del mismo numero de documento pero solo me sale 1

[image: lo que me sale] Esto es lo que sale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que  no estás iterando la lista que obtienes de cada `key`, solamente  consideras el primer elemento `lista[0]`. Algo así deberías de hacer:

```
  foreach (var key in hashDiccionari.Keys) // bucle para sacar todos las opciones por id
    {

        List<DTO.Cl_LineaAC> lista = hashDiccionari[key];
        // Itero la lista
        foreach(var lineaAC in lista)
        {
           Cl_LineaAC_Final linFin = new Cl_LineaAC_Final();

           string doc = lineaAC.documento;
           linFin.documento = (doc.PadLeft(6));
           string fec = lineaAC.fechaAsiento;
           CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
           var fechaDatetime = DateTime.ParseExact(fec, "yyyyMMdd", provider);
           var fechasalida = fechaDatetime.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
           linFin.fecha= fechasalida;
        

           dt.Rows.Add(linFin.documento, linFin.fecha);
       }
    }
```